# Newbie to AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have tried AsyncTask as others suggested when trying to send http request to PC server.
The variable resultString was created and assigned a voice recognition result. The codes before this part worked just fine.

The  problematic code is as belowed:

```
private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, String> {



private String URL = "http://192.168.1.100:9080/" + "?" +"content1="+resultString;
//buf.append("content1="+URLEncoder.encode(resultString,"UTF-8"));
AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");
//Log.e("check", "succeed");
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... param) {

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
    //Log.e("check1","succeed");
    Log.e("url",URL);
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    try {
        Log.e("check3","succeed");
        return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);


    } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("check4","succeed");


    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("check5","succeed");


    }
    Log.e("check6","succeed");//to this point
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (null != mClient)
        mClient.close();
    //Log.e("check6","succeed");
    mTextView.setText(result);

}
}
```

the execute part looks like this at the end of the whole codes:

```
new HttpGetTask().execute();
```

**Logcat**

```
 03-06 14:57:07.117: W/System.err(12451): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException:
 Connect to /192.168.1.100:9080 timed out 03-06 14:57:07.137: W/System.err(12451): 
 at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
 03-06 14:57:07.137: W/System.err(12451): at 
 org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
```

the Log shows that there is an `IOException` in my codes and the value of `mClient` will eventually be `null`.I have looked online for the same situation and it seems this occurs when data takes too much time to respond that is requested. And many of the answers suggested I should reset Timeout and allow more time for the request to be sent.(Maybe the network is unreliable..) But I don't really understand where to put the reset codes in my situation. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your URL :-

```
http://192.168.1.100:9080/
```

Is Working fine or not. The exception is ConnectTimeoutException which points to the fact that the URL is inaccessible at all.